# Unable Send Data From Matlab To DSPIC 30f4011

Tags: matlab, pic, matlab-deployment

I am facing some problems while trying to send data from Matlab To DSPIC30f4011 through USB to UART Converter. Here is my code:

```
function comparison()

    global x1 y1 

    s=serial('COM3');
    set(s,'BaudRate',9600);

    fopen(s);
    fprintf(s,'2');
    out=fscanf(s);
    fclose(s);
```

But my circuit board is unable to receive the data. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Receive:
I always had problems receiving data from a serial port, so I used a mex file GetSerialData.cpp, but right now I can't figure were came from.

Send:
To send data correctly it is really important that you got the right baud rate and COM-port. You could check the com-port in your windows device manager. Mine shows up in the (COM & LPT) group as USB Serial Port (COM7).
The baud rate depends on your DSPIC30F4011 device, which you probably also have to configure.